# bounding a difference knowing a bound on a ratio, or does continuity imply its converse?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Suppose that for $x,y>0$ I know that $$ \frac yx=1- \epsilon$$
for some small $\epsilon$.
Is there any way to bound $x-y$ knowing this? It seems clear to me that this means $x\sim y$ and also, obviously, $y<x$, so I feel there should be some $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that

$$0<x-y<\delta $$

I can see that $x-y=\epsilon x$, thus if $x<1$ we get $x-y< \epsilon$. Is there anything better?

We can see it a different way as some sort of converse of continuity: consider the function $f(x)=\frac xy$ for a fixed $y\in \mathbb R$. $f$ is clearly continuous at $x=y$, hence for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $\left|\frac{x}{y}-1\right|<\epsilon$. Is the reverse true? Is it true that for all $\delta>0$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $\left|\frac{x}{y}-1\right|<\epsilon$ implies $|x-y|<\delta$?

Comment: X/Y cannot be naturally connected to $X-Y$ but to $\log X - \log Y$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that can't be done if you don't have more information about either $x$ or $y$.

You got already $x-y = \epsilon x$, and it should be clear now that if $x$ can take arbitrary high values, then for fixed $\epsilon$, the term $\epsilon x$ can take arbitrary high values as well.

For a numerical example,

$$\frac{999}{1000}=\frac{9990}{10000}=\frac{9990000}{10000000}=0.999=1-0.001,$$
and by adding more and more zeroes (the same amount) at the end of enumerator and denominator, you can get the difference of them as big as you want, while keeping their quotient $0.999$.